# How I update a Child node in Firebase Realtime Database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I went to update Child node.
If the user went to change the oldPhoneNumber then his/her oldPhoneNumber matched with the database and then his/her NewPhoneNumber should be updated in the place of the oldPhoneNumber, but I couldn't update this Child node. My database structure like -

```
{
  distributer{
    +919073701479{  //this data or the oldphoneNumber change to NewPhoneNumber or the new data
         -NGGyw0gIpIX_clCxooo:"gc2ie3ba06b53d2"
         -NGzKSSPmz2XCB711H8d:"gc2ie07671a91e3"
         -NH-URwvbvLCFLxqAZcy:"gc2ie3a8b3b49b0"
     }
  }
}
```

My Code is -

```
db.ref('/distributer').orderByKey().equalTo('OldphoneNumber').once("value", snapshot => {
         if (snapshot.exists()){
           snapshot.forEach(function(element){
             let userData = element.key;
             console.log(userData);
             userData.ref.child('OldphoneNumber').set('NewPhoneNumber')
             .then(()=>{
               alert("data update successfully");
             })
             .catch((error)=>{
                 alert("unsuccessful,error"+error);
             });
           })
         }
       })
```

But It's not work. How can I update that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the operation. Can you show: 1) the hard-coded value of `localStorage.getItem('phoneNumber')` and `localStorage.getItem('pNumber')`? 2) What you want the data structure to look like after the code has run?

Comment: yes, localStorage.getItem('phoneNumber') is user's old phone number and localStorage.getItem('pNumber') is user's new phone number .  if user change his/her old phone number the he enter the new phone number , which I store in localstorage.

Comment: after update the the data base **+919073701479** this data or old phone number will be changed and new data or new phone number update here.

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information.